# Window.Close is not Working with this URL

Tags: javascript

why is this not working? I mean, it works with any page, but with this page (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom)  it doesn't

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <button onclick="openWin()">Open w3schools.com in a new window</button>
    <button onclick="closeWin()">Close the new window (w3schools.com)</button>

    <script>
    var myWindow;

    function openWin() {
      myWindow = window.open("https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-%E2%80%94-best-ad-blocker/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom", "_blank", "width=500, height=500");
    }

    function closeWin() {
      myWindow.close();
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_close2

Comment: It does work with Firefox but not with Chrome. I suspect it might be a security feature by Chrome, perhaps.